# Как отсчитать время в Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Пишу бота для тг, надо, чтобы бот отвечал пользователю через два часа после старта. Как это можно хорошо организовать?

Comment: библиотеку или фреймворк используешь?

Comment: Имеете ввиду для написания бота? Юзаю telebot

Comment: на start или после первого сообщения пользователя, запоминайте chat_id, и напишите через него сообщение пользователю

Comment: import time

# старт таймера
begin_time = time.time()

# выполняем продолжительное действие
time.sleep(1)

# получаем время окончания действия с начала запуска таймера
end_time = time.time()
print end_time - begin_time

# другое продолжительное действие
time.sleep(2)

# получаем время окончания действия с начала запуска таймера
end_time = time.time()
print end_time - begin_time

Comment: Что-то пошло не так.. Хотел сказать, а чем не вариант в самом пайтоне использовать таймер из коробки?

Answer (score 1):

Простой пример реализации - в отдельном потоке (почитайте про асинхронность):

```
import time
from threading import Thread

class my_users:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def post_msg(self):
        time.sleep(7200)
        # написать пользователю

user1 = my_users()
Thread(target = user1.post_msg).start()
```

Comment: `target = user1.post_msg()` тут проблема, т.к. в target попадает не ссылка на функцию, а результат ее выполнения. Т.е. ваш код тоже самое что: `Thread(target=None).start()`, а нужно так: `Thread(target=user1.post_msg).start()`

Comment: спасибо, поправил

Comment: Зачем делать такой  костыль когда есть `threading.Timer` ?